# Determining a basis for $\text{Range}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been doing one exercise and I don't understand one step of the logic, so I would be grateful if you could explain. This is the exercise:
[image]

I will briefly explain up to which point I got: First I find out the solution space V, which is:
[image]

Then I input this into:

[image]
and I get  this: [image]

---

This is where I got. Now it says in the solutions: Consequently, $\text{Range}(T)$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose first coordinate is $0$, so the basis is: $\{ (0, 1, 0),(0, 0, 1) \}$

My question: How is it concluded that $\text{Range}(T)$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and why is the basis of it $\{(0, 1, 0),(0, 0, 1)\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of $T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and it follows from your computations that the first coordinate of each element of the range is $0$. On the other hand, the range has dimension *at least* $2$. For instance, putting $r=1$ and $s=t=0$, you get that $(0,0,5)$ is in the range. And putting $r=s=0$ and $t=1$, you get that $(0,7,1)$ is in the range. But $(0,0,5)$ and $(0,7,1)$ are linearly independent. And the only subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with dmension at least $2$ and such that the first coordinate of each element is $0$ is $\{(0,a,b)\,|\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. A basis of this space is $\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why does the range have a dimension of at least 2?

Comment: @Relax295 Because it has two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: I understand. But what does 'at least' stand for? How could it have i.e. 3?

Comment: @Relax295 Not in this case. But when a vector space has two linearly independent vectors, its dimension is at least $2$.